# Not able to assign value to hidden form field using form_alter hook

Tags: 7, entities, forms

I have a form in which field `my_consultant_id` is "Hidden integer" type field and having widget type as "Hidden field".

I am assigning the value to this field by using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)

```
function threebl_summary_report_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'eck__entity__form_add_summary_report_comparative_client_gro‌​up') {
        global $user; 
        $form['field_created_by']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = (int) $user->uid;
    }
}
```

But not able to set the value for that field.

If I inspect the form it shows html code for field like:

```
<div class="field-type-field-hidden-integer field-name-field-my-consultant-id field-widget-field-hidden form-wrapper" id="edit-field-my-consultant-id">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors or it does not store the value to the database? The form submit handler is custom (share the code) or default?

Comment: No errors...It does not store the value in database. I checked the value of $user->uid its correct

Comment: Check this out: https://www.drupal.org/node/728398#comment-11519357

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it by validate handler of the form. Using validate handler I assigned my value to the form variable before submit.

In form alter hook call validate handler like below

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_module_name_form_validate';
```

And following is the validate handler function code

```
function my_module_name_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {    
$form['field_my_field']['#parents'] = array('field_my_field');
form_set_value($form['field_my_field'],array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $new_value))),$form_state);
```

}

For reference please go through [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7.x)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing default value.

try

```
$form["my_consultant_id"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = (int)$user->uid;
```